# results of FgenesH and GenScan

Tags: bioinformatics

Why FgenesH and Genscan don't give good results as I have prdicted number of genes of Chromosome 16 which according to NCBI are 86 but the results I have obtained are 57 genes predicted by FgenesH and only 47 genes predicted by GenScan. why they have done missed predictions. Kindly help me to know the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be mistaken to assume that a computer program that is predicting, or classifying, the biological features in a nucleic acid or protein sequence is infallible.

Different programs use different algorithms and will have different parameters for their models of what a gene looks like. Typically they are tested on a learning or training set of features, and optimized to yield the highest score on that training set.  Then when you feed in your novel sequence and ask the program to predict where the genes are it will hopefully give you a list of predictions along with an estimated probability of the confidence of that prediction. However there will always be outliers, actual protein-coding genes that have atypical features not contained in the training set.

In other words, each program is only as reliable as its underlying model, and nobody has a perfect model.

Comment: Ok i get it that these methods are not reliable but my problem is that I was using Chicken Chromosome 16 for which FgenesH is trained so my question is that if its parameter is trained for chicken then why don't it give me missed prediction?